# Can't dismiss ProgressDialog in Android app

Tags: android, progressdialog

I am a beginner Android programmer. Trying to use AsyncTask and ProgressDialog but encountered a problem -- the ProgressDialog is unable to be dismissed.

The following codes are inside an importExportActivity which extends Activity --

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {    
    ProgressDialog dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(importExportActivity.this);

    protected void onPreExecute() {
          this.dialog1.show(importExportActivity.this, "",
                                  "Please wait for few seconds...", true);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(final Void success) {
          dialog1.dismiss();
    }

    protected Void doInBackground(final Void ... args) {
               ...... did the main logic ....
          return null;
    }
 }
```

Done a lot of google search but can't seem to find a solution to this.

Can someone help?

Comment: Does `doInBackground(Void ...)` ever complete?  If it doesn't, your `ProgessDialog` will not dismiss...

Comment: Yes - please post the "main logic" code.

Comment: Make final your Progress dialog

Comment: Ha ha .... silly me, managed to find the solution. Apparently, I am only able to post the answer 7 hours later. In any case, the problem was that the line -- "ProgressDialog dialog1 = new ProgressDialog(importExportActivity.this);" should change to "ProgressDialog dialog1;" and the line "this.dialog1.show(importExpor ...." should change to "ProgressDialog.show(importExpor".

Comment: Thanks guys ..... this site is fantastic. Learnt a lot !!! :-)

Comment: Add your answer later then. And set the answer so that the question will be removed from the unanswered list

Answer (score 2):

I think you are not returning :

```
 @Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void success) {
      dialog1.dismiss();
    return;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Answering my own question. The following worked:

```
public class ProgressTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {    
ProgressDialog dialog1; 

protected void onPreExecute() {
      dialog1 = ProgressDialog.show(importExportActivity.this, "",
                              "Please wait for few seconds...", true);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void success) {
      dialog1.dismiss();
}

protected Void doInBackground(final Void ... args) {
           ...... did the main logic ....
      return null;
}
```

}

Comment: You should mark your own answer as the answer to this question. This would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void onPreExecute() {
      this.dialog1.show(importExportActivity.this, "",
                              "Please wait for few seconds...", true);
      super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(final Void success) {
      dialog1.dismiss();
      super.onPostExecute(RESULT);
}
```

mine is working this way ...